# (Modifying JSFiddle) How do I make an additional level dropdown based on what was selected on the previous dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, cascadingdropdown

i am using this jsfiddle as a reference: https://jsfiddle.net/patelriki13/m1ezs70o/

which is a cascading dropdown using countries as items. I am trying to add another level to this, where instead of 4 levels, it would be 5. I've tried to add another set of objects that are street names before the "zips" and adding another onchange function for it based off of one of the onchange functions below, but it's not working. How do I go about in achieving this?

HTML:

```
<form name="myform" id="myForm">
  <select id="countySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Country --</option>
    </select>
     <br>
    <br>
  
    <select id="stateSel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select State--</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>    
    <select id="citySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select City--</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select id="zipSel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Zip--</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var countryStateInfo = {
    "USA": {
        "California": {
            "Los Angeles": ["90001", "90002", "90003", "90004"],
            "San Diego": ["92093", "92101"]
        },
        "Texas": {
            "Dallas": ["75201", "75202"],
            "Austin": ["73301", "73344"]
        }
    },
    "India": {
        "Assam": {
            "Dispur": ["781005"],
            "Guwahati" : ["781030", "781030"]
        },
        "Gujarat": {
            "Vadodara" : ["390011", "390020"],
            "Surat" : ["395006", "395002"]
        }
    }
}


window.onload = function () {
    
    //Get html elements
    var countySel = document.getElementById("countySel");
    var stateSel = document.getElementById("stateSel"); 
    var citySel = document.getElementById("citySel");
    var zipSel = document.getElementById("zipSel");
    
    //Load countries
    for (var country in countryStateInfo) {
        countySel.options[countySel.options.length] = new Option(country, country);
    }
    
    //County Changed
    countySel.onchange = function () {
         
         stateSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
         citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
         zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
         
         if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
             return; // done
         
         for (var state in countryStateInfo[this.value]) {
             stateSel.options[stateSel.options.length] = new Option(state, state);
         }
    }
    
    //State Changed
    stateSel.onchange = function () {        
         
         citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
         zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
         
         if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
             return; // done
         
         for (var city in countryStateInfo[countySel.value][this.value]) {
             citySel.options[citySel.options.length] = new Option(city, city);
         }
    }
    
    //City Changed
    citySel.onchange = function () {
        zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
            return; // done
        
        var zips = countryStateInfo[countySel.value][stateSel.value][this.value];
        for (var i = 0; i < zips.length; i++) {
            zipSel.options[zipSel.options.length] = new Option(zips[i], zips[i]);
        }
    }   
}
```

Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.